# Calculating superellipse shape in dart

Tags: math, dart, flutter, shapes

I want to create a superellipse shape in Flutter for a widget.

I found an article about creating superellipses written in python and java, but i can't quite get the code to work.

[Link to article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/implementing-a-superellipse/)

```
class SuperEllipse extends ShapeBorder {

  final BorderSide side;
  final double n;

  SuperEllipse({
    @required this.n,
    this.side = BorderSide.none,
  }) : assert(side != null);

  @override
  EdgeInsetsGeometry get dimensions => EdgeInsets.all(side.width);

  @override
  ShapeBorder scale(double t) {
    return SuperEllipse(
      side: side.scale(t),
      n: n,
    );
  }

  @override
    Path getInnerPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection textDirection}) {
    return _superEllipsePath(rect, n);
  }

  @override
    Path getOuterPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection textDirection}) {
    return _superEllipsePath(rect, n);
  }

  static Path _superEllipsePath(Rect rect, double n) {

    final int a = 200;
    List<double> points = [a + 1.0];
    Path path = new Path();
    path.moveTo(a.toDouble(), 0);

    // Calculate first quadrant.
    for (int x = a; x >= 0; x--) {
      points[x] = pow(pow(a, n) - pow(x, n), 1 / n);
      path.lineTo(x.toDouble(), -points[x]);
    }

    // Mirror to other quadrants.
    for (int x = 0; x <= a; x++) {
      path.lineTo(x.toDouble(), points[x]);
    }
    for (int x = a; x >= 0; x--) {
      path.lineTo(-x.toDouble(), points[x]);
    }
    for (int x = 0; x <= a; x++) {
      path.lineTo(-x.toDouble(), -points[x]);
    }

    return path;

  }

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Rect rect, {TextDirection textDirection}) {
    Path path = getOuterPath(rect.deflate(side.width / 2.0), textDirection: textDirection);
    canvas.drawPath(path, side.toPaint());
  }

}
```

I want to return the correct shape, but instead I get an Exception: Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 200.
For some reason the variable `a` isn't allowed to be 200? I don't know why, and changing it to 0 doesn't produce any errors, but then there is no shape either.

Does anyone know if there is a better way of doing this?

Comment: see https://www.figma.com/blog/desperately-seeking-squircles/

Comment: I'm not sure how that article is helpful... I need help with my code, I understand what a superellipse and a squircle is.

Comment: i though you really wanted the case where n >= 4

Comment: That's not the problem, The problem is that I'm getting an Exception when I use the Shape

Comment: ok so what is you exact stacktrace (3-4 top frames)?

Comment: `I/flutter (24060): #0      List._setIndexed (dart:core/runtime/libgrowable_array.dart:151:72)`  

`I/flutter (24060): #1      List.[]= (dart:core/runtime/libgrowable_array.dart:148:5)`  

`I/flutter (24060): #2      SuperEllipse._superEllipsePath (package:superellipse_test/superellipse.dart:46:13)`  

`I/flutter (24060): #3      SuperEllipse.getOuterPath (package:superellipse_test/superellipse.dart:34:12)`

Comment: in `points[x] = ...` your `x` index is == 200 (since it is initialized with `int x = a`) but length of `points` array is == 1

Comment: btw the stack trace `superellipse.dart:46:13` points out to the source of your problem: file:`superellipse.dart`, line:`46`, column:`13`

Comment: I see. I am getting a shape now. Do you have any idea how I can calculate the Y axis as well? Right now I'm only calculating with the X axis

Comment: i dont get it: you call `path.lineTo` so you have the complete `Path` - it is returned from `_superEllipsePath` method

Comment: [Image](https://imgur.com/a/LQu4jjt)

I am getting a shape, but it is supposed to be centered, since it's wrapped in a 100x100 centered `Container` widget. I figured that's because I'm doing something wrong with the axis? Or maybe I'm starting the path in the wrong place.

Comment: run `flutter run lib/superellipse.dart` fron the terminal, press `p` key and take the screenshot again (or simply use [this](https://flutter.io/docs/testing/debugging#visual-debugging))

Comment: [New image](https://imgur.com/a/UL7XNnh)

Comment: well, now it is obvious ;-) - your path is set outside your bounds

Comment: you have to use `Rect rect` parameter instead of using `final int a = 200;`

Comment: I'm trying that right now, but I can't seem to get it to work...

I'm thinking the issue may be in `points[x] = pow(pow(a, n) - pow(x, n), 1 / n);`

Comment: If I change the path to start at the center of the shape, the points are still as they were before...  

[image](https://imgur.com/a/x3Cbp9j)

Comment: simply use `Rect rect` parameter and not fixed `200` - you are computing one quadrant so you have to divide the side by 2 and then to `shift()` your final `Path`

Comment: I am using the rect parameter. The first loop looks like this now: This is the code behind the image:  

    `for (int x = width.toInt(); x >= 0; x--) {
      points[x] = pow(pow(width, n) - pow(x, n), 1 / n);
      path.lineTo(x.toDouble(), -points[x]);
    }`

Comment: It works perfectly now :) Thank you very much!

Comment: sure, your welcome

Comment: of course you have revert `paint` method to your version as i tested it with some hardcoded `Paint`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a class for this in flutter, it is called **ContinuousRectangleBorder**.

```
    Material(
    color: Colors.red,
    shape: ContinuousRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
    ),
    child: Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(40,0),
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Center(child: Text('Hello World')),
    ),
  )
```

you can also use it directly in container with **decoration: ShapeDecoration(shape: ContinuousRectangleBorder())**

```
Container(
    decoration: ShapeDecoration(
      color: Colors.red,
      shape: ContinuousRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(70.0),
      ),
    ),
    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 40, 10, 40),
    // margin: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
    child: Center(child: Text('Hello World')),
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

came across this package that produces squircles

https://pub.dev/packages/cupertino_rounded_corners

i'm sure you can dig around the code to find out how it makes the shape